# How increase the clickable zone around my Icon before select?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I use an clickable icon when it selected the background change to grey. But the zone around the icon when it is unselected is not clickable for select it and when it selected the zone around is clickable for unselected it.

I try to change padding, margin and more and nothing

this is my icon before selection:

[image]

and this after selection:

[image]

So when the icon is unselected the zone around (who have the same size of grey when it selected) is clickable but don't work for selected it. But if it selected when click on the grey zone that's unselected it.

```
<Icon
    type="book"
    onClick={e => this.onChangeIcon(e, project)}
    style={{
       height: 34,
       width: 44,
       fontSize: 30,
       alignItems: "center",
       justifyContent: "center",
       color:
       "book" === project.imagePath
        ? "white"
        : "#363636",
        backgroundColor:
        "book" === project.imagePath
        ? "#363636"
        : "white",
        borderRadius: "10px",
        marginRight: "10px",
        marginLeft: "10px",
        marginTop: "2px",
        paddingTop: "3px",
        display: "inline-block",
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can wrap element around `PIcon` and write its width & height like this

```
<div style={{width: '300'; heigth: '400'; cursor: 'pointer'; background: 'transparent'}} onClick={yourEvent}>
    <PIcon />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it but, no change when I click on the div with the pointeur is curson. No effet on the selection of the icon and I put well my function in onClick method of div balise.  but when I click on my icon I have juste always the icon with the grey background as in my question